# Multiple results for single record with multiple table variable value T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a single record set, where I want to merge all the table variable values to this single record set which result in multiple record set.

Ex: I have  table A with column c1, c2, c3

```
declare @fnum table (fnum varchar(10))

insert into @fnum
select xc1 from x where xc='some condition' ---(results in multiple records)

select c1, c2, c3 , (select fnum  from @fnum ) from A where c3='some condition'
```

The table A returns a single record for c3 condition. But when I do the last select it should display multiple records set for each table variable value. I dont want to use any loop . How can I process it?

Comment: Why don't cross join table x and A to get all the values you need? `Select c1,c2,c3,xc1 from A cross join x where xc= 'some condition' and c3 = 'some condition '`

Comment: Yes, we can use cross join but in my requirement table values coming through multiple if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
select c1, c2, c3 , (STUFF((SELECT ', ' + fnum  FROM @fnum
     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT).value('root[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')) from A where c3='some condition'
```

You can put any delimiter instead of ', ' in the query. but don't forget to adjust length parameter of STUFF function. Here ', ' consists of 2 chars, so I set length = 2 for STUFF function.

Comment: It return all the values in a single row using delimiter. I need multiple rows with different table variable values.

Comment: oh sorry, didn't understand the task right. I can think of only this solution for now: 

SELECT fnum ,
(SELECT c1 FROM A WHERE c3 = 'condition'),
(SELECT C2 FROM A WHERE c3 = 'condition'),
(SELECT C3 FROM A WHERE c3 = 'condition')
FROM @fnum